# Developing Java application within Box Enterprise to upload Files

Tags: java, box

We currently have the Box.com enterprise license but this is the first time when we are trying to develop a Java application to upload some Files. The requirement is to upload Files by a batch application and also provide access to a third party company personnel outside of our company to download those Files. I would like to know the steps that are required to do this. Based on my reading of the API documentation I understood the following. Please validate if it looks good and also add anything that I'm missing.

(1) For an application to upload Files a service account needs to be created. And the service account will have its own content that it will manage. I have couple of questions regarding this step.
How to create a service account which will just have access to its content ?
How would we give access to a third party company personnel to download those files ?
Whats the difference between an App user and a service account ?

(2) The service account will use Outh 2.0 with JWT to do the authentication. Please let me know if there is any Java code sample using Box SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account is basically the JWT app that you create in the developers console.

https://github.com/kendomen/BoxJavaJWTExamples/blob/master/src/com/nike/box/UploadFileAsEnterpriseAdmin.java

Comment: Thanks for the response. How the service account and App user account needs to be setup. Is it done by the developers or the Admins ?

Comment: You get the service account like this:  BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppEnterpriseConnection(
ENTERPRISE_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, encryptionPref, accessTokenCache);

Comment: Thanks again @kendomen. Do I also need to setup an App user account to use Box Content API ?

Comment: No you don't necessarily need to.  You can just use the service account to upload files and share.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm creating the service account, is it tied to my account in someway. What I'm looking for is a generic account for an application.

Comment: It's not tied to your account.  It's a generic application account.